# form increases size when resizing using button

Tags: vb.net

so I removed the borders of my program to have my own custom ui into it, so of course I have to make a way to resize it. i do this by using a button, but when it is on the bottom-right sides of the screen the program increases its size by a lot but it can still be resized, and when it's on the top left side it still does it but only increases the size by a little.

also I know there are other ways, but for me this one's the easiest, it's just that the button increases it's own size for some reason.

here's the code:

```
Private Sub tim_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tim.Tick
    Me.Size = MousePosition
End Sub

Private Sub res_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles res.MouseDown
    tim.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub res_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles res.MouseUp
    tim.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intent correctly, what you are missing is the `Control.PointToClient` method.  It converts MousePosition from coordinates on your screen to coordinates on your form.

Here's a modified version of your code.

```
Private Sub tim_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tim.Tick
    Dim curpos As Point = PointToClient(MousePosition)
    Size = New Size(curpos.X + (Size.Width - ClientSize.Width), curpos.Y + (Size.Height - ClientSize.Height))

    'if your form has no border you can skip the above and just use: 
    '  Size = PointToClient(MousePosition)
End Sub

Private Sub res_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles res.MouseDown
    Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(ClientRectangle.Size)
    Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE
    tim.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub res_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles res.MouseUp
    Cursor = Cursors.Default
    tim.Enabled = False
End Sub
```